# How can I edit saved games in Civ V?

Tags: civilization-5

Are there any saved game editors for Civilization V

I was initially interested in changing the difficulty mid game, but a save file editor could open up whole new avenues of fun :)

Comment: Perhaps this should be re-worded to *'How can I edit saved games in Civ V?'* ?

Comment: You can use bmaupin's save game editor to edit several settings of a saved game, see here:  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73480/is-there-any-way-to-change-victory-conditions-with-the-game-already-started/273907#273907

Comment: There is actually a web version to make it easy to edit the save game: https://bmaupin.github.io/civ5save-editor/

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Not that it's not possible, just no one ever made one (IIRC, there was a save editor for pre-expansion Civ4, but nothing afterwards)

However, there is a mod that lets you edit many many things ingame (eg/ terrain, techs, diplomacy, etc) that probably covers most of what you would want.

[IGE](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=77002777)