# Disable the 2050 limit in Civ 5 once I've started the game

Tags: civilization-5

I've already started a game in Civ 5. I'm pretty far in and would like to disable the 2050 limit (I wasn't aware of this when I started the game).

Is there a way to do it so that I don't reset my game? Also, I would prefer not having to click the "One... More... Turn..." button because winning by time isn't very much fun.

Comment: I've gotten passed the 2050 limit. I think someone just has to win before 2050. When I did it, someone had already won before 2050, and i decided to continue. Although i also never founded a city. Then my unit was pushed off the map and the AIs kept playing well into the 3000's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally playing after the end would be accomplished by simply clicking the One... More... Turn... button after the game ends from time. However, this does prevent other victories from being won.

The only other way to change the maximum turns in game would be to edit the save file. This would require a hex editor and a lot more knowledge than I can give you. You could also try using the World Builder to edit your save and turn it into a scenario.

Finally, some quick googling found the [Ingame Editor mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=77002777). I don't know if it can do what you're trying to do but it looks like it's capable of making a lot of changes in game. It's plausible this could change the max turns (or even the current turn number- that would have that desired effect).

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple web app that will let you change the game parameters of a save file, including max turns: [Civilization V save editor](https://bmaupin.github.io/civ5save-editor/)

Just open your save file in the app and uncheck *Time victory* (it will automatically set *Max turns* to 0). Then download the save file with the changes and open it in the game.

There are a couple alternative options that require either installing the SDK or editing the save file by hand. You can read more details on those here: [Is there any way to change victory conditions with the game already started?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73480/154341)

Comment: You're getting awful close to the spam line; four posts back to back, all promoting your application. Even with disclosure, that makes 80% of your contributions about your promotions.

Comment: @Frank yeah that's a good point. I thought my app might be helpful so after editing this post I started looking for other questions that my app might help solve. In case it makes a difference it's an open-source app that brings me no revenue whatsoever. I'm also an active user on other SE sites. But it sounds like I need to take it down a notch. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Frank I just read the [policy on self-promoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/206677). Makes sense. Please let me know if there's any corrective action I should take. I don't mind deleting answers if need be.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done without editing the save file itself. I’m still looking for a save file editor myself. So far the best thing I’ve found is the [In Game Editor](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=77002777)