# How to continue beyond turn 100 in the Scramble for Africa scenario?

Tags: civilization-5

I was having a lot of fun with the Scramble for Africa scenario until I reached turn 100 and discovered that, unlike other scenarios, it is impossible to continue playing.

So, is there anyway to edit the scenario settings, e.g. some settings file or a level editor, in order to continue playing after turn 100?

Comment: You can try using the Scenario Editor to change the turn count to something very high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue by editing the scrambleafricascenario/turnsremaining.lua file [as suggested here](https://github.com/bmaupin/civ5save-editor/issues/4); I'm summarizing the solution below:

> Use a text editor like notepad to open the "turnsremaining.lua" file,
>   located at SteamApps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization
>   V/steamassets/assets/dlc/expansion2/scenarios/scrambleafricascenario/turnsremaining.lua.
>
> Find the line below and change ***100*** to whatever number of maximum turns
>   you want for the game (tested OK with 300):
>
> *local iTurnsRemaining = **100** - Game.GetGameTurn();*
>
> Next, find the line below and change ***g_kiGameTurnLength*** to the same
>   value you inserted on the previous line:
>
> *local iTurnsRemaining = **g_kiGameTurnLength** - Game.GetGameTurn();*

After this, the "Just one more turn" button will be enabled in the Scramble for Africa scenario, even for an ongoing saved game.

Also, bmaupin's Save Game Editor allows you to change several settings of a saved game, namely enabling the Culture UI, see the following for more detail: [Is there any way to change victory conditions with the game already started?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73480/is-there-any-way-to-change-victory-conditions-with-the-game-already-started/273907#273907)

There is actually a web version to make it easy to edit the saved game: https://bmaupin.github.io/civ5save-editor/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play longer than 100 turns, do as described in this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/323669), and change values in both lines to any you like, but it won't enable "play one more turn" after that. To enable the "play one more turn" button, you go to the section `Game Event Handlers`, and change the following line:

`PreGame.SetGameOption("GAMEOPTION_NO_EXTENDED_PLAY", true); - No extended play allowed`

to `false` in the end.

All done. The same applies to any other scenario file.